# No adapter attached: skipping layout & null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In this program, I try to display data from a `recyclerview` inside `recyclerview`,following the illustration:
[image: illustration recyclerview inside recyclerview]

From the illustration above, I made 2 different `recyclerview`, beside the `checkbox` is a `recyclerview` **parent** and below it is a `recyclerview` **child**. So, in this case I made 2 items & adapters to connect the two lists to each other.here is some code i attached

ParentAdapter class: https://codeshare.io/GqegmZ

ParentItem class: https://codeshare.io/aJXZMZ

ChildAdapter class: https://codeshare.io/5zmRAD

ChildItem class: https://codeshare.io/G6b8Wp

below I attach the two classes in terms of sending data

Activity sending data: https://codeshare.io/5ow7Zp

Fragment fetch data: https://codeshare.io/GkO4Z3

after you see some code i attached, i use `serializable` method for data fetching. but there are some errors that i get.
in activity class:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_impian_list);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    ImpianAdapter adapter = new ImpianAdapter(items, getActivity());
    //null object reference
    items = (ArrayList<ImpianItem>) getArguments().getSerializable("Data");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

From the code above I get 2 errors, the first is the **null object reference** and the **skipping layout**. is there a solution regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send `ArrayList<ImpianItem>`

```
items = (ArrayList<ImpianItem>) getArguments().getSerializable("Data");
ImpianAdapter adapter = new ImpianAdapter(items, getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: but, how to call an adapter from the `ImpianAdapter` (AdapterParent) in fragment class? because the `HabitsAdapter` (AdapterChild) class has been implemented in the `ImpianAdapter` class, and how do you call the `serializable` method and put it in the `ImpianAdapter` class?